# Drupal core in subdir / index outside

Tags: drupal-7

I have installed Drupal7 in a subdir http://foo.com/site, and I want to keep it there.

However, I would like urls like http://foo.com/node/101 to be available *as well* as http://foo.com/site/node/101. The latter would stay the canonical url.

I was hoping I could just move index.php up and modify some things, much like wordpress. But I cant find detailed instructions anywhere. Does anyone know ?

Answer (score 1):

You should never move index.php outside of the Drupal folder or hack into the Drupal core. This would get you a maintenance hell whenever you'll need to update your Drupal core.

Instead, you can use URL rewrite to create redirects (HTTP 301, permanent). Assuming you're running Apache, you can use mod_rewrite and create a `.htaccess` file in the server's document root with rewrite rules in it. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^node/(.*)$ site/node/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can modify the rewrite rule, or add new ones for additional matched to redirect.

Comment: that would be RewriteRule ^node/(.*)$ site/node/$1 [R=301,L]